# Reboot of Linode Xen VPS and Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx, xen, linode

I have a Rails 4 application with PostgreSQL running on a Linode Ubuntu 14.04 server with Xen hypervisor. Linode support sent me a notice saying that they will be conducting maintenance on Xen tomorrow morning. There is a 2 hour window where my VPS will be down.

What should I do to prepare for the reboot? I plan to back up the database but I'm not sure what else to expect. The application is running with passenger on NGINX. Will NGINX restart automatically? Will I have to repopulate my database with the dump I make? Please help because I can't afford a lot of down time.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fine. This is pretty standard for most VPS's and it happens with some regularity. Xen is the 'under the covers' stuff Linode uses to manage virtual servers, but should not effect anything on your server. Should not be any different than if you were reboot your server manually with `sudo reboot`.